# Пропадает связь между объектами

Tags: c#

Имеется массив `inv` класса `ItemInInv`, в другом классе `InstantiateItem` есть свойство `item`, которое равно `ItemInInv item = inv[n]`. Если изменить любое свойство в объекте item, тогда это свойство измениться в массиве. А еще у меня есть чудесная функция:

```
public void ReplaceItems(ref ItemInInv Last, ref ItemInInv New)
{
    ItemInInv temp = (ItemInInv)Last.Clone();
    Last = New;
    New = temp;
}
```

После выполнения функции связь между объектом и массивом пропадает, а мне это не нужно.[image: Графическое описание]
Как мне сохранить связь после выполнения функции?

[Пример нерабочего кода](https://pastebin.com/pkuX77Hb):

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            item[] items = new item[5];

            for(int i = 0;i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                items[i] = new item();
            }
            OutputArray(items);
            item n = items[0];
            item x = items[1];

            Change(ref n,ref x);
            OutputArray(items);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void Change(ref item Last,ref item New)
        {
            item temp = (item)Last.Clone();
            Last = New;
            New = temp;
        }
        public static void OutputArray(item[] a)
        {
            foreach(item n in a)
            {
                Console.Write(n.id + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    class item : ICloneable
    {
        public static Random random = new Random();
        public int id;
        public item()
        {
            id = random.Next(0, 255);
        }
        public object Clone()
        {
            return this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Полный код приведите с инициализацией массива и передачей элемента в функцию.

Comment: @iluxa1810, Инициализация массива в инспекторе Unity.
`owner.Equip(ref item);` 
`public void Equip(ref ItemInInv item){
                ReplaceItems(ref equipment[5], ref item);
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде, все логично:

Массив по определенному индексу хранит ссылки на элементы.

Вы взяли ссылку и сохранили ее в отдельную переменную:

```
item n = items[0];
item x = items[1];
Change(ref n,ref x);
```

И уже у **ЭТОЙ** переменной вы меняете ссылку, **НО** массив ничего об этом не знает и продолжает хранить старую ссылку по индексу.

Если 10 переменных ссылаются на один и тот же объект и вы одному из них присвоите `null`, то это не будет значить то, что все остальные элементы так же получат `null`.

Что бы все работало как вы хотите, вы должны передавать ссылки напрямую из массива без посредников:

```
Change(ref items[0], ref items[1]);
```

Comment: Когда я вызываю функцию, меняется значение только у объекта item, а массив остается неизменным. Мне нужно, если изменить содержимое item, значение в массиве менялось соответственно.

Comment: @XMarin можете в вопрос добавить минимальный самодостаточный пример, что бы я его мог скопипастить и выполнить у себя?

Comment: добавил ссылку на PasteBin